# correct way to handle exit from infinite loop in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

In my apps i find the need to have infinite while loops mostly to do some repeated action continuosly unless another event takes place so what i am doing is

```
while(chkFlag)
{
   //do something here which takes around 30 seconds
}
```

Then in some other event say a button press to stop the loop i do

```
chkFlag = false;
```

Now this does the work but the problem is this does not stop the loop instantaneously as the chkFlag is checked only after the complete execution of the loop takes place. So can anybody please tell me how i can exit a loop instantaneouly based on an event.

Comment: What sort of event are you talking about?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "blocking" code should likely be moved into some kind of worker thread (which can be terminated and/or have the results discarded). If using a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) (recommended, as it makes this simple), there is built-in support to handle a cancel operation.

Then the loop can either be moved inside the BackgroundWorker or the completion (RunWorkerCompleted) event of the worker can trigger the next worker to start (which causes an implicit loop).

Happy coding.

---

There are more "aggressive" ways of terminating/signaling a thread; but suggesting these would require more information than present.

Comment: i forgot to tell that i am running this within a thread and damn i forgot it myself simply calling thread.abort did the trick.(with exceptions ofcourse)

Comment: @swordfish Just keep in mind that Thread.Abort can be very dangerous, depending.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `break;`.

I suppose, based on the anonymous downvoter, I should elaborate. The syntax above will immediately exit the loop that you are in (it works in the other loops as well; it's probably worth noting that `continue` exists to restart the loop at the beginning, which will perform increment logic in `for`-style loops).

How you decide to execute `break` is up to you, but it must be within the loop itself.

There are multiple approaches to this, such as placing checks for the event within the loop and calling `break;` if it occurs. Others have noted the other approaches with BackgroundWorkers and Cancel Tokens (this is preferred given it's not within the loop).

Comment: scattering break statements across the loop didnt seem like a good idea to me thats why i asked it here.

Comment: Fair enough. I just read the question and mistook it as you didn't know about `break`. That's mainly why I posted it.

Answer (score 1):

you can't make it exit instantly (well, you could run the loop in a new thread and [Abort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.abort.aspx) it, if it's really safe to have an exception thrown from it at any time), but you could scatter `if(!chkFlag) break;` at various points within the loop that it's safe to exit. The usual method of doing this is to use a `BackgroundWorker` or a `CancellationToken` rather than a simple boolean flag.

Of course, it will still need to be run in another thread so that the button event can run at all. BackgroundWorker will take care of this automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you want to use a new thread? What are you doing for 30 seconds in the loop. Sounds like maybe there's a better design to use.

Have you considered using a timer, or setting up an event handler?